# HUGO checking for the existence of a variable in a shortcode

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I need to check the variable "text" in a shortcode, if it exists then `{{ .Inner | markdownify}}`

It is important that the variable simply exists and has no value and the shock code does not need to be closed if there is "text" `{{<toc text>}}`

I tried this solution but it gives an ERROR: *failed to extract shortcode: shortcode "toc" must be closed or self-closed*

```
{{ if isset .Params `text` }}
    <div class="col">
        {{ .Inner | markdownify }}
    </div>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
{{ if isset .Params.text }}
    <div class="col">
        {{ .Inner | markdownify }}
    </div>
{{ end }}
```